# Virtual Environment not activated after restarting VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed the `python` extension for VSCode, and then created a new virtualenv `.venv` in my project directory.

If I press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and select my environment, then open a new Terminal session, the new environment is automatically activated. However if I close VSCode and re-open it, then open a new Terminal session, the new environment isn't automatically activated. I can again manually activate it, however I would like it to activate automatically every time I open my project.

In my settings.json, I have tried using the following which was automatically filled by the extension:

```
"python.pythonPath": ".venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
```

as well as

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe"
```

Additionally, launching python and running the following indicates that it is using my root installation and no virtual environment:

```
>> import sys
>> sys.prefix
'C:\\Python37'
```

How can I get VSCode to automatically activate my environment after launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the terminal before the Python extension has finished loading -- e.g. immediately after a restart -- then the terminal won't be activated because the extension isn't running yet to tell VS Code to run the command. Once you view a Python file then the extension will be triggered to load, and then once it's done -- you can tell as the message in the status bar about the loading will be gone -- then the terminal will automatically activate the virtual environment.

Comment: thanks for sharing this. FWIW, i got similar results except it didn't matter whether i had opened a Python file. if i closed a project window with the terminal open, when i re-opened the window, the terminal window would open automatically and the venv would _not_ be activated. if i closed a project window with the terminal closed, when i re-opened the window and manually opened a new terminal, the venv _would_ be activated.

Comment: @EricS. The Python extension activates not just on opening a Python file but if we detect you are working in a Python project (e.g., `pyproject.toml` exists).